# Ask for password once submit is clicked

Tags: php, webforms, password-protection

I have created a form for use by students at work and the idea is that they complete the form based on a procedure they have completed. The form is then checked by a tutor and they tutors adds his/her comments before submitting the information to a database.

How can I set the form up to ask for a password, when the submit button i clicked? As I don't want students to login in and complete the form and just submit click before the tutor looks at it to check the information they have entered is correct.

Is this possible?

UPDATE:
The form is all on one page and I want the students to complete the first few fields then the staff member to complete the rest. But when they click "update database" I want the form to ask for a staff password
Here is a picture 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/mattcripps/5887541880/

Comment: I'm not sure what you wan't to do, but why don't you just integrate the password input field into the form?

Comment: I have a password to log into the site but I want something else to be entered by a superviser/tutor like a password to confirm what the student has entered on the form is correct. For example with this 2nd form of validation a student could simply login complete the form saying they had completed a procdure, give themself a score on that procedure and then simply submit it without the tutor actually checking the information they entered was correct

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking there involves using [SESSIONS](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to pass the students data from the form page to the next. An alternative would be to include the password on the form the students complete rather than sending them to a new page to just enter a password.

However, if you do want it on a separate page you can either take a look at jQuery's dialog boxes so once submit is pressed a dialog box is presented to enter a password, or simply pass the form `$_POST` data to a session and process the password on a separate page.

**Update**

From your comment below as I understand you are looking for something similar to this:

1) Student logs in
2) Student completes part 1 of form and submits
3) Teacher/Admin logs in and selects students form and completes part 2.
4) Teacher submits finalised form with part 1 and 2 complete.

For this I would suggest the following database schema:

```
studentsTbl  
  student_id  |  int(11)
  password    |  varchar(128)
  pass_salt   |  varchar(64)
  ... (etc)

teachersTbl
  teacher_id  |  int(11)
  password    |  varchar(128)
  pass_salt   |  varchar(64)
  ... (etc)

studentFormTbl
  form_id     |  int(11)
  question1   |  text
  ... (etc)  

completedFormTbl
  form_id     |  int(11)
  question1   |  text
  admin1      |  text
  admin2      |  text
  ... (etc)
```

The user then logs in using the details from the `studentsTbl`, submits the form as required which is then stored in the `studentFormTbl` for review by the teacher/admin. The admin then selects the form to review, change anything as required / add notes and finally submits it to completed forms.

Obviously you need to mould this to as you want it, changing `question1` to more descriptive fields etc.

Comment: Sorry maybe I have not made myself clear. The students login to the site/form and complete it filling in information about what procedure they completed. The staff member then scores them on the same form and submits it to a database. What I don't want to happen is for the student to complete both the student and staff section and submit the form into the database without the tutor confirming that information is correct

Comment: Thanks for that. What I actually have currently is just one form with all the fields. So the student opens the form. Completes the first few fields which outline the procedure that they took and any comments they may have about the procedure. The staff member then walks to the student station/desk and completes the remain fields which are grade for the procedure and comments and submits the form. 
I should add that these forms are web based completed on a tablet device. 
I just dont want the student to enter the grade and staff comments and submit the form

Comment: @Mattrsa - Would is be feasible then to have all the fields on one page separated into two areas (student and teacher) and preventing the form to be submitted until all fields and the correct teacher password is entered?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to achieve really. I want one form that at the end the staff member must enter a password to submit

Comment: What I would do then is do a simple form layout with the student section at the top with the staff section at the bottom. What the student can then do is call the teacher over to complete the second half of the form which also includes a submission password. The form can't be submitted without the teacher password so leaving access open for students that may potentially attempt to complete the staff section shouldn't cause an issue.

Comment: So I should simply add a field at the bottom of the form which looks to stored passwords in a database as I have done with my login page and if the field is blank make sure the form does not get submitted

Comment: @Mattrsa - Thats what I would suggest. I'd add the field just above the submit button. Then do a simple password check to only submit the form if the password is correct. Just remember that once submitted, if the password is incorrect the information entered isn't stored by default and will require a session to repopulate the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could display a jQuery Dialog box like the ones in this example.
http://kailashnadh.name/code/jqdialog/

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the signup form and details form. after registering, the details form may display to fill details , take that form details to tutor authorization and submit to database.